# Select rows from dataframe with same values on several columns but different value on another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with four feature columns and one label column. There is some issue with the dataset. There are some rows with the same values for the features but are labelled differently. I know how to find duplicates for multiple columns using

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

How do I find duplicate features with conflicting labels though?

For example in the dataframe like this

```
    a    b    c    label
0   1    1    2     y
1   1    1    2     x
2   1    1    2     x
3   2    2    2     z
4   2    2    2     z
```

I want to output something below

```
a    b    c    label
1    1    2    y
1    1    2    x
```

Comment: [df.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: You can provide the `subset` param to [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) (and `drop_duplicates`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

```
df[df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['label'].transform('nunique') > 1]
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c label
0  1  1  2     y
1  1  1  2     x
2  1  1  2     x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of columns to the `subset` parameter of `.duplicated()` to only consider those columns when checking for duplicates.

In your case, you would call `df.duplicated(subset=["a", "b", "c"], keep=False)`.

Comment: I don't need to know the duplicates, I would like to drop the duplicates. But I still end up with lots of records because there are lots of records with unique feature values to begin with. I want to filter out these and only end up with the ones that have duplicate values for features but different labels. Sort of like groupby features and pick the ones out with nunique of label greater than 1